# Renders with Fresnel, ColorMap, and Toon BSDF don't look right

Tags: linux

I'm spanking new to Blender (as in < 1 day), so this may be a false alarm, but a simple object with Fresnel/ColorMap/Toon BSDF is rendering black with Eevee. Even the Cycles render doesn't look right (or consistent, it gave different results when I tried it twice).

Build: Blender 2.8 beta (a38205fbd801 of 2019-03-14)
Platform: Linux (Fedora 29)
My model: https://www.dropbox.com/s/r58thvhxy58uq0k/Toon.blend?dl=1

[image: Setup]
[image: Eevee Render]
[image: Cycles Render]

BTW, I'm very impressed with the first few hours of playing with Blender 2.8. I am a Lightwave user looking to switch and have been checking out Maya, which looked really consistent and intuitive, when I heard of Blender 2.8 and its new design...and I must say so far it looks even more consistent and intuitive.

Comment: An object looks shiny because it reflects elements in the environment. Is there anything to be reflected on the glossy surface?

Comment: Thanks. The issue is that the object renders completely black (image 2 above) with Eevee. I explored this some more with different combinations, and it looks like Toon BSDF is just not implemented yet with Eevee in 2.8: the same node structure with Toon BSDF replaced with say Principled BSDF renders as it should. I guess I'll just wait because I understand they're adding these one by one.